# XPath for Json String

Tags: json, xml-parsing, jsonpath

I have JSON string like below :

```
{
    "ConfigurationJsonResult":
    [
        2246,
        2247,
        2248,
        2249,
        2250,
        2251,
        2252,
        2253,
        2254,
        2255
    ]
}
```

My problem is i want to get 1st value i.e 2246 using xPath.

I have tried using **/ConfigurationJsonResult[1]** but it gives me **[2246,2247.....2255]**, i just want 2246. How to achieve it.

Comment: Is it possible to navigate a JSON String with XPath??

Comment: yes , read here http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: It is called `JSONPath` according to the link and it is not `XPath`

Comment: but you can read json values using XPath.....

Comment: @Popeye the link you have posted describes a library to parse json data using jsonpath which is analogous to xpath but not xpath itself. With standard js functions you cannot do it. However you can translate a xpath to jsonpath and do it using  simple function.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a mapping function to convert xpath to jsonpath and use converted string to access the data.

```
function xpathToJsonPath(xpath) {
   var jsonPath = xpath.replace("//","..");
   //Simillarly other mappings
   return jsonPath;
}

var data = jsonPath(object, xpathToJsonPath("$..author"));
```

Mappings are given the link you have shared - http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

You can do plenty of improvements on this like extending this as a function to prototype etc.

Comment: In some regards such a translation is actually a nice idea. It's also possible to take a json file, `json.reads()` it and then print it as xml to use libxml2 support. For the given usecase it's too much of an overhead though, imho.